# How to set the color of the badgeValue in UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbaritem

How do I set the color of the badgeValue in UITabBarItem. The default red color signals that something is wrong - in my case it is just information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no (official) way to do this.
The documentation makes it pretty clear:

> **badgeValue**
>
> Text that is displayed in the upper-right corner of the item with a *surrounding red oval*.

(from Apple's documentation)